# Error Loading json file on elasticsearch aws

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've just set up an elasticsearch domain using `Elastic search service` from aws. 
Now I want to feed it with some json file using:
 `curl -XPOST   'my-aws-domain-here/_bulk/' --data-binary @base_enquete.json`
according to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-upload-data.html).

My json file looks like the following:

`[{"INDID": "10040","DATENQ": "29/7/2013","Name": "LANDIS MADAGASCAR SA"},
{"INDID": "10050","DATENQ": "14/8/2013","Name": "MADAFOOD SA","M101P": ""}]`

which gives me this error:

`{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]","status":400}`

I tried without `[` and `]` same error!

Note that I already set up access policy to be open to the world for dev stage purpose.

Any help of any kind will be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the wrong format of data.
Please go through the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

Ideally it should be in format -

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

This means that content of the file you are sending should be in following format -

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{"INDID": "10040","DATENQ": "29/7/2013","Name": "LANDIS MADAGASCAR SA"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{"INDID": "10050","DATENQ": "14/8/2013","Name": "MADAFOOD SA","M101P": ""}
```

Comment: Thanks Vineeth, I've missed this documentation. Actually It solves the  problem but It raises another problem. My json file is large so I need to programmatically add these meta_data.